# Формирование договора в word/doc исходя из введенных клиентом данных

Tags: javascript, php, ms-word, forms, doc

Возникла потребность для нашего сайта создать форму, в которой человек будет заполнять поля (Фио, адрес, документы), а после нажатия кнопки отправить, будет формироваться документ из введенных данных и отправляться на почту клиенту. Как мне лучше реализовать данный функционал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать уже готовое решение: https://blog.mayflower.de/6699-phpword-create-documents.html

Или вариант для [pdf](http://www.fpdf.org/)